# How to get the SMS date from messenger?

Tags: android, date, time, cursor, sms

Android default messenger sort SMS in several groups using received time(picture).
I am trying to show sms inbox in custom listview like default messenger using cursor:

```
    // Create Inbox box URI
    Uri inboxURI = Uri.parse( "content://sms/inbox" );
    // List required columns
    String[] reqCols = new String[]{"_id", "address", "body", "date"};
    // Get Content Resolver object, which will deal with Content
    // Provider
    ContentResolver contentResolver = getContentResolver();
    // Fetch Inbox SMS Message from Built-in Content Provider
    Cursor cursor = contentResolver.query( inboxURI, reqCols, null, null,
            null );


    sms = new ArrayList<>();
    String date = "";
    cursor.moveToLast();
    while (cursor.moveToPrevious() || cursor.isLast()) {
        //to get phone number
        address = cursor.getString( cursor.getColumnIndex( "address" ) );
        //to get massage
        body = cursor.getString( cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow( "body" ) );
        //to get date of sms
        date = cursor.getString( cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow( "date" ) );
        Long timestamp = Long.parseLong( date );
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.setTimeInMillis( timestamp );
        Date finalDate = calendar.getTime();
        smsDate = finalDate.toString();
```

but it is not working like that.It's like "Sun Aug 12 07:13:13 .....". I want to show time same as default messenger. What is the solution?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Sms tables, Dates are stored as INTEGER in milliseconds. so, use

```
 long sms_time= cur.getLong(cur.getColumnIndexOrThrow("date")) on Cursor.
```

This is the time in milli on which the SMS was recieved. Now Get The Current Time In Milli Seconds.

```
 long now = System.currentTimeMillis();//get Current Time
```

now Calculate M=Difference In Minutes:

```
long minutes=(now - sms_time)/(1000*60);
```

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13138710/3155082