# Read sms received after given time

Tags: java, android

In my project I need to access sms which received after given time. For example it can be get all sms which I received after 1538633990932 . This time is in millis. I make the project which getting all messages in inbox. but i need to access sms received after specific time.

```
    List<String> sms = new ArrayList<String>();
    Uri uriSMSURI = Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox");
    Cursor cur = c.getContentResolver().query(uriSMSURI, null, null, null, null);

    while (cur != null && cur.moveToNext()) {
        String address = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex("address"));
        String body = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndexOrThrow("body"));


    }

    if (cur != null) {
        cur.close();
    }
```

I think I need to declare the time in the query.

Comment: have a look on it.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9713021/reading-sms-received-after-a-date

Answer (score 1):

You have to pass the epoch value in the filter.

```
String filter = "date>=" + 1538633990932;
Cursor cur = c.getContentResolver().query(uriSMSURI, null, filter, null, null);
```

Taken from [this](http://realembed.blogspot.com/2013/11/retrieve-sms-message-on-particular-date.html) post.